# Difference between `vector<int> v;` and `vector<int> v = vector<int>();`

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

What is the difference between

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

and

```
std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>();
```

Intuitively, I would never use the second version but I am not sure if there is any difference. It feels to me that the second line is simply a default constructor building a temporary object that is then moved by a move assignment operator.

I am wondering whether the second line is not somehow equivalent to

```
std::vector<int> v = *(new std::vector<int>());
```

hence causing the vector itself to be on the heap (dynamically allocated). If it is the case, then the first line would probably be preferred for most cases.

**How do these lines of code differ?**

Comment: Even when there are temporary objects, they won't be on the heap.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Starting from C++17 there's no difference whatsoever.

There's one niche use case where the `std::vector = std::vector` initialization syntax is quite useful (albeit not for default construction): when one wants to supply a "count, value" initializer for `std::vector<int>` member of a class directly in the class's definition:

```
struct S {
  std::vector<int> v; // Want to supply `(5, 42)` initializer here. How?
};
```

In-class initializers support only `=` or `{}` syntax, meaning that we cannot just say

```
struct S {
  std::vector<int> v(5, 42); // Error
};
```

If we use

```
struct S {
  std::vector<int> v{ 5, 42 }; // or = { 5, 42 }
};
```

the compiler will interpret it as a list of values instead of "count, value" pair, which is not what we want.

So, one proper way to do it is

```
struct S {
  std::vector<int> v = std::vector(5, 42);
};
```

Comment: What changed in C++17 to mean there's now no difference? What was the difference in C++14?

Answer (score 21):

The 1st one is [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), the 2nd one is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization); The effect is same here, i.e. initialize the object `v` via the default constructor of `std::vector`.

For `std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>();`, in concept it will construct a temporary `std::vector` then use it to move-construct the object `v` (note there's no assignment here). According to the [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17 it's guaranteed), it'll just call the default constructor to initialize `v` directly.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The
>   objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would
>   otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be
>   present or accessible, as the language rules ensure that no copy/move
>   operation takes place, even conceptually:
>
> - In the initialization of a variable, when the initializer expression
>     is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the
>     variable type:
>
>   ```
>   T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>   ```

(Before C++17, the copy elision is an optimization.)

> this is an optimization: even when it takes place and the copy/move (since C++11) constructor is not called, it still must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all),

BTW: For both cases, no `std::vector` objects (including potential temporary) will be constructed with dynamic storage duration via `new` expression.

Answer (score -1):

You had asked:

> What is the difference between
>
> ```
> std::vector<int> v;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>();
> ```
>
> ?

As others have stated since C++17 there basically is no difference. Now as for preference of which one to use, I would suggest the following:

- If you are creating an empty vector to be filled out later then the first version is the more desirable candidate.
- If you are constructing a vector with either a default value as one of its members and or a specified count, then the later version would be the one to use.
- Note that the following two are different constructors though:

  - `std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>();`
  - Is not the same constructor as:
  - `std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>( 3, 10 );`
  - The 2<sup>nd</sup> version of the constructor is an overloaded constructor.
- Otherwise if you are constructing a vector from a set of numbers than you have the following options:

  - `std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };`
  - [operator=( std::initializer_list)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)
  - `std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };`
  - [list_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Here is the list of `std::vector` [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: "Now as for preference" I would say for preference `auto v = std::vector<int>();` is better.

Comment: @Slava It depends on the situation. Sometimes you don't want to bloat your code with `auto` everywhere. Nothing wrong with using it in specific places, but not for everything. If you are using a ranged loop then by all means use auto to traverse through a container. However just to declare a variable; I prefer to see the container with its types so I know what the container details. Another example that is a bad case use for using auto is when using some 3rd party libraries such as Eigen. They have lazy evaluation on some things but not all and the `auto` feature can lead to UB.